When AngularJS render the HTML elements?
I have Cannot read properties of undefined reading rate error in the browsers console for a web app developed using AngularJS.
HTML code:
....
    <div ng-if="!GetTaxController.getMinimumTax()>
       ....
    </div>
....

Controller code:
self.taxes;
    
let getTaxes = function(){
    TaxService.getTaxes()
    .then(function(taxes) { 
        self.taxes = taxes;
    },function() {
    })
}
    
self.getMinimumTax = function() {
    //Algorithm that calculates minimum tax using self.taxes.rate;
    ...
    return minimumTax
}
  
getTaxes();

I noticed the getMinimunTax function is called before self.taxes is fetched from the server so self.taxes.rate is still not defined when the function is executed.
¿How should I work with AngularJS in this case? I guess when a controller property used in the HTML is still not defined (cause its still being retrieved from server using async call) the HTML element is not yet rendered by AngularJS but in this case the HTML element is using a controller function so its defined so AngularJS renders the element. ¿Am I right?
This question is not similar to How to use ng-if with async data . That one is about a controller property being assigned a wrong value (and its fixed just fixing the expression used in the assignment), this one is about using a controller function instead a controller property.

This question is similar to: How to use ng-if with async data. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@SyndRain The question is different. The one you provided is about a controller property being always false cause it was assigned a wrong expression (res.message is used instead res.data.message). In my case Im not even using a controller property (I know that way it should work) but a controller function instead. So my question still is how to work when the html directive uses a controller function instead a controller property?

Apologies, you’re right it’s a different question. I’ve only  read the title and answer of it. However, I’ve linked it because I think this can be easily solved by using a scope variable directly like the linked answer post. You could update that variable only after the fetch is done (or even after the minimal tax is calculated if that’s what you were trying to do).

"HTML element is using a controller function so its defined so AngularJS renders the element." No, ng-if don't render the element if the method evaluates to false. !GetTaxController.getMinimumTax() is probably resulting in something like !NAN (depends on how you're algorithm handles the undefined self.taxes), which evaluates to true.  You could also manually trigger the digest after the fetch but its usually not preferred.

@SyndRain Even if I use a scope variable its needed first to perform the calculus with the values fetched from the server. I guess the solution would be to perform the calculus after the fetch is done then assign the result to a scope variable, all inside the ‘then’ body
